# Target-specific Variables as Prerequisites in a Makefile

Tags: build-process, build, dependencies, makefile

I'm trying to write a GNU make Makefile which has a load of similar targets, where the build commands vary slightly between them.
I'm trying to use [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) to represent these variations. Some of these variable values refer to files I want to use as prerequisites. For example:

```
target_1:special_filename=target1_prereq
target_2:special_filename=target2_prereq

target_1 target_2: common_filename $(special_filename)
    do_something common_filename --a-weird-option=$(special_filename)
```

When I call 'make target_1', I want it to make target1_prereq if it doesn't exist. At the moment, it doesn't seem to use target1_prereq as a prerequisite, even though the build command (do_something) is called with the right parameter.

I'm using GNU Make 3.80.

---

Edit:
A few more complications from the real system. Some of the variables are themselves based on the values of other variables. Manually specifying the prerequisites wouldn't scale.
A slightly more complicated example:

```
target_1:special_filename_base=target1_prereq
target_2:special_filename_base=target2_prereq

some_filename_a = $(special_filename_base).exta
some_filename_b = $(special_filename_base).extb

target_1 target_2: common_filename $(special_filename_b) $(special_filename_a)
    do_something common_filename --a-weird-option=$(special_filename_a) --second=$(special_filename_b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A target-specific variable is defined only in the target's commands (or in other target-specific assignments); it can't be used as one of the target's prereqs. I don't think there's a clean way to do what you want in Make, but there are several kludgey approaches, such as the following:

```
EXTENSIONS = .exta .extb
target_1: $(addprefix target1_prereq,$(EXTENSIONS))
target_2: $(addprefix target2_prereq,$(EXTENSIONS))

target_1 target_2: common_filename
    do_something common_filename --a-weird-option=$(filter %.exta,$^) --second=$(filter %.extb,$^)
```

Comment: Resurrecting this thread for the benefit of anyone else who stumbles across it. A [more elegant solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311743/make-using-target-specific-variables-in-prerequisites) uses secondary expansion.

Comment: @Seth, I agree: `target_1 target_2: common_filename $$(special_filename_base).exta $$(special_filename_base).extb ...`

Answer (score 3):

As a simple workaround:

```
target_1:special_filename=target1_prereq
target_1:target1_prereq
target_2:special_filename=target2_prereq
target_2:target2_prereq

target_1 target_2: common_filename $(special_filename)
    do_something common_filename --a-weird-option=$(special_filename)
```

There is some redundancy, but it is localized, so it's not too bad.

Comment: I guess that solves the specific case I posted, but I was hoping for a more general solution.

I'll edit with a more complicated example.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a rather clean way of side-stepping this limitation. It'd go something like this:

```
target_1:export special_filename_base=target1_prereq
target_2:export special_filename_base=target2_prereq

some_filename_a = $(special_filename_base).exta
some_filename_b = $(special_filename_base).extb

target_1 target_2:
    $(MAKE) -f $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) target-proxy

target-proxy: common_filename $(special_filename_b) $(special_filename_a)
    do_something common_filename --a-weird-option=$(special_filename_a) --second=$(special_filename_b)
```

Two important points:

1. `export` the target variables, so that they'll be accessible when we re-run the Makefile.
2. Create a proxy target that has all the original prerequisites of `target_1 target_2` and in `target_1 target_2` invoke the Makefile again with this proxy target. Since the target specific variables will have values by then (we *are* in the recipe by that time) *and* they were `export`ed, they'll be available in `target-proxy` - voila :)

The downside of this approach is that we are creating another `make` process - if it's just another one then it's probably ok, but YMMV so be extra careful.

Comment: Indeed looks like recursive use of make is the option to go. By doing so prerequisites can be declared top-level and the struggle of building prerequisite list is avoided. Thanks for this answer.