# my makefile's target-specific variable doesn't affect recursively expanded variables

Tags: variables, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Target-specific Variables as Prerequisites in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340060/target-specific-variables-as-prerequisites-in-a-makefile)

In my makefile (rather simplified below) I have a target-specific variable that needs to influence a recursively expanded variable, but it's not doing so - leaving me sitting here scratching my head:

```
NAME            = MyProg
OBJECTS         = $(OD)/main.o
RD              = Release
OD              = Foo

all: OD = $(RD)
all: $(OD) $(OD)/$(NAME).elf

$(OD):
    mkdir $(OD)

$(OD)/$(NAME).elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o "$@" $^

$(OD)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -Wa,-a="$(OD)/$*.lst" -o "$@" "$<"
```

The command that actually gets executed is as follows:

```
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -c -Wa,-a="Release/main.lst" -o "Foo/main.o" "main.c"
```

$(OD) is correctly evaluated in the ".lst" expression, but incorrectly by $(OBJECTS).  It must be that $(OBJECTS) is evaluating $(OD) outside my rule... so is it possible to correct this behavior?  Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The Make manual says this about target-specific variables

> "these values are only available
>   within the context of a target's
>   command script (and in other
>   target-specific assignments). " [1](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)

and I guess this is what you are seeing, the target-specific
variable is not expanded in targets themselves.

What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like $(OBJECTS) to expand to "Release/main.o" instead of "Foo/main.o"; I had thought that variables were lazily evaluated, so that this is how it would be expanded.

Comment: I understand that, but what I mean to ask is why Release must be target specific. What is the scenario when it has some other value?
Do you have a "debug" target and want to put the debug object files
in a Debug directory?

Comment: yes - as I said, the posted makefile was very much over-simplified.