# Use make variable in builtin shell function in a Makefile

Tags: python, shell, build, makefile

I have this make file

```
all : CONFIG=config.ini
debug : CONFIG=config-debug.ini

CONFIG_FILES := $(shell python parse_config.py -i $(CONFIG))

all: $(CONFIG) $(CONFIG_FILES)
    echo $(CONFIG) $(CONFIG_FILES)
```

When I run `make all` it shows some python error saying `-i` option param is missing. So it seems `$(CONFIG)` is not going through `shell` function.

How can `make all` invoke `python parse_config.py -i 'config.ini'`?

same way `make debug` invoke `python parse_config.py -i 'config-debug.ini'`?

**Update**:

After running `make all SHELL+=-x` I get following output.

```
+ python parse_config.py -p static -i
usage: parse_config.py [-h] -i INPUT_JSB3 [-p PREFIX]
parse_config.py: error: argument -i: expected one argument
```

But after that I get

```
+ python parse_config.py -p static -i static/config.ini
```

And make seems to continue to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`MAKECMDGOALS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html#Goals) variable.

```
ifeq ($(findstring debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),debug)
CONFIG=config-debug.ini
else
CONFIG=config.ini
endif

CONFIG_FILES := $(shell python parse_config.py -i $(CONFIG))

all: $(CONFIG) $(CONFIG_FILES)
    echo $(CONFIG) $(CONFIG_FILES)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this:

```
all : CONFIG=config.ini

all: $(CONFIG) $(CONFIG_FILES)
        ...
```

will not work.  The value of target-specific variables are *only* available *inside* the recipe.  You cannot use target-specific variables as prerequisites.  That's also why it's not set within the `$(CONFIG_FILES)` variable when you use it in the prerequisites list.

ETA:

You can do something like this:

```
CONFIG_FILES = $1 $(shell python parse_config.py -i $1)

all: $(call CONFIG_FILES,config.ini)
debug: $(call CONFIG_FILES,config-debug.ini)
```

perhaps.  You could write it out explicitly.  You could run a recursive make invocation overriding CONFIG_FILES.  You could auto-generate included files.  You could define some variables then use secondary expansion.  There are a *lot* of ways to do this.

You just can't do it with target-specific variables in the prerequisites list.

Comment: `parse_config.py` provides a list of files. How do I use that list as prerequisite then? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use target-specific variables and simple assignment together like that. You are telling make to run the shell command at make parse time but also telling it to only set the contents of the `$(CONFIG)` variable during specific target contexts.

You can either use a recursive variable (and run the shell command once for each time you use the variable) or stick `CONFIG_FILES` assignments into each target-specific context along with `CONFIG`.

Comment: any example about `recursive variable`?

Comment: Normal `=` assignment is `recursively expanded variable` in make terms as compared to the `simply expanded variable` that is assigned with `:=`.

Comment: Well, using `=` only doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `:` from the `CONFIG_FILES := …` line.  That forces `make` to evaluate the `CONFIG_FILES` at that point in the makefile, and it doesn't have the context of a target (`all` or `debug`) to allow it to provide a value for `$(CONFIG)` so it doesn't provide one, which leads to the error you see.

Use:

```
CONFIG_FILES = $(shell python parse_config.py -i $(CONFIG))
```

Comment: This should work (and is what I was saying in my answer as well). Add the edited makefile to the question please and give us the exact make output. Also the output from `make all SHELL+=-x`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im:  What happens if you remove the `$(CONFIG_FILES)` from the dependencies on the `all` line?  If things start to work better, I have some theories; if they don't, my theories are immaterial.  But I probably won't be able to respond again for some hours.