# make: Using target specific variables in prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a Makefile where prerequisites using target specific variables

```
version=

target1: override version=1
target1: package

target2: override version=2
target2: package

package: dir=package-${version}\
package: source

source: src/${version}.c
```

When i run make the version variable is in target package and source empty.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

package: dir=package-$${version}
package: source

source: src/$${version}.c
```

### UPD.

This answer is wrong, the suggested code won't work because of the reasons explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22690338/545027) to a similar question.

**TL;DR:** Target-specific variables take their effect *based on the target that make is currently building* [[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)]. Second expansion, in turn, takes place *right at the end of the read-in phase* [[2](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion)], before building anything.

Thanks to [@koniiiik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687488/koniiiik) for pointing out.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work; even with secondary expansion, the prerequisite of `source` in the above Makefile is `src/.c`, because of the reasons explained in http://stackoverflow.com/q/22679137/687488 and the answer there...

Comment: @koniiiik That example from your doesn't work because of the target-specific nature of the `DEP` variable. Try to change it to a regular one, and everything will work. This particular answer _does_ work since the `version` variable is not target-specific.

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't work for me – I copy-pasted the code from above, and when I run `make target1` with GNU Make 4.1, the output I get is `make: *** No rule to make target 'src/.c', needed by 'source'.  Stop.`

Comment: @koniiiik It seems, you're right, and indeed it doesn't work for me as well. I must have checked the code before posting it. Also the `version` variable _is_ target-specific here. Thank you for your remark and sorry for the confusion, I'll fix the answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm just sorry that there doesn't appear to be a way to make this work, other than duplicating parts of the Makefile…