# Target-specific variables in a makefile & prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm seeing unexpected results for target-specfic variables in GNU make.

What I want is to set a target-specific variable that affects dependencies. I can use `.SECONDEXPANSION` to achieve that.

```
some-target: DEP := debug-dep

debug: some-target

.SECONDEXPANSION:
some-target: $$(DEP)
    @echo $^

debug-dep:
```

`make debug` prints `debug-dep`.

---

Now I read that [make defines target-specific variables for descendant rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

> When you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc.

But when I change my makefile to have the variable set on "parent" target:

```
debug: DEP := debug-dep

debug: some-target

.SECONDEXPANSION:
some-target: $$(DEP)
    @echo $^

debug-dep:
```

and do `make debug` I get a blank line.

This seems to contradict the documented behavior of target-specific variables. Is there something that I am missing?

---

This is sort of similar to [make: Using target specific variables in prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311743/make-using-target-specific-variables-in-prerequisites), but what I am doing isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that target-specific variables are not set until the targets are being run (if you add `@echo '$(DEP)'` to your `some-target` body in that second case you will see that it is set) but that second expansion happens immediately after the initial read-in phase.

I was going to say that I'm actually surprised that this works in the first case at all (and speculate as to why) but then I pulled up the manual for a minute and while reading about `.SECONDEXPANSION` I found the [following](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

> [T]he true power of this feature only becomes apparent when you discover that secondary expansions always take place within the scope of the automatic variables for that target. This means that you can use variables such as $@, $*, etc. during the second expansion and they will have their expected values, just as in the recipe. All you have to do is defer the expansion by escaping the $. Also, secondary expansion occurs for both explicit and implicit (pattern) rules.

Which explains your behaviour exactly. The expansion only sees variables set in the scope of the target and the prerequisite inheriting only happens at target evaluation time (since it depends on target prerequisites).

Answer (score 0):

All variables are set in the first read-in phase. It is true no matter it is a global variable, or a target-specific variable (or a pattern-specific variable).

There is no such thing that is like the other answer says

> target-specific variables are not set until the targets are being run

See the example Makefile below,

```
GA = ga
GB = $(GA)
GC := $(GA)

a: aTA = $(GA)
a: aTB := $(GA)
a: aTC = $(aTA)
a: b;
GA = ga2

b: bTA = $(aTA)
b: bTB := $(aTA)
b: bTC := $(bTA)
b:;
```

After the first read-in phase, all variables are set (*therefore, `aTB` is `ga`, not `ga2`*). They are as follows respectively,

- GA is literal `ga2`
- GB is literal `$(GA)`
- GC is literal `ga`
- aTA is literal `$(GA)`
- aTB is literal `ga`
- aTC is literal `$(aTA)`
- bTA is literal `$(aTA)`
- bTB is literal   (empty)
- bTC is literal   (empty)

Although they are all set, they are not visible everywhere, they have scope. E.g.,

- Global variables' scope is everywhere
- Target-specific variables' scope is

  - the target's other target-specific variables
  - the recipe of the target
  - the recipes of the target's prerequisites

    *This is the only reason that we could see `bTA` is eventually expanded to `ga2` if we use `bTA` in the target `b`'s recipe.*
  - the prerequisite-literal appearing in the target's rule when using `.SECONDEXPANSION`

    ***This is why the 1st case in OP's question works.***

The following is NOT the scope of a target-specific variable,

- everywhere in the parent target
- the target-specific variables of the target's prerequisites

  *This is why `bTB` and `bTC` are both empty.*
- the (sub) prerequisite-literal appearing in the rule of the target's prerequisites (whether using `.SECONDEXPANSION` or not)

  ***This is why the 2nd case in OP's question doesn't work.***