# makefile target-specific files

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to make a single makefile file that compiles two different set of files. Is this posible?

What I tried so far is:

```
target1: OBJ = foo1.o foo2.o  
target1: application

target2: OBJ = foo3.o foo4.o
target2: application

application: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $(OBJ)
```

What happens is that `LD` is called with the correct parameters but make never actually checks the dependencies therefore the implicit rules that compile .c files to .o are never executed so linker fails with:

```
ld: cannot find foo1.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find foo2.o: No such file or directory
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You were right. Corrected the minimal code that produces the error

Comment: target-specific variables are available in the *recipe* and in other target-specific assignments for the same target. But they're not available in the prerequisites (since they might depend on automatic variables which have no value until the prerequisites are determined). Perhaps there is a way to do this, but it seems like the traditional explicit prerequisite style is simpler. That is, if you delete  `OBJ =` from `target1: OBJ = foo1.o foo2.o` you end up with the equally maintainable `target1: foo1.o foo2.o`. :)

Comment: @EtanReisner: What makes you think it has prerequisites? I tested this with a makefile: `target: prereq=foo` `target: $(prereq)` `\techo $^`. If the target-specific variable was available in the prerequisites, I would expect to see `foo`. But no. (The recipe for a target without prerequisites is executed unconditionally, ¿no?)

Comment: @EtanReisner: In the *recipes* of their prerequisites, but not the prerequisites of their prerequisites. AFAICT. Change the sample Makefile to `target1: prereq=foo` `target1: target2` `target2: $(prereq)` `\techo $^` and it still prints nothing. (That was actually my original test, based on the OP.) (But add `echo $(prereq)` to the recipe for target2 and you can see that it does have a value at that point.)

Comment: @rici Ah... I see. My apologies. I didn't fully consider the duplication of `$(OBJ)` in the `application` recipe. You are (as I probably should have assumed from the start =) correct.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Well, thanks, but I don't feel totally on solid ground about `make`. I've just learned a few tricks, some of them the hard way. Target-specific variables are seductive but I don't always predict the behaviour correctly, which is why I tried it before commenting, and why I commented instead of answering. Although I will stand by the suggestion that just writing out the prerequisites is not more work than making a target-specific list of prerequisites, at least in this case, and it requires considerably less thought. :)

Comment: I'm a bit hard-pressed to come up with a good solution to this problem other than the suggested literal prerequisite writing (which might invert the order of the prerequisites and `application` which would be a problem here). The only other options I can think of offhand involve generated targets, etc.

Comment: @Etan: One possible way to inherit a target-specific variable setting into a prerequisite's prerequisite would be to use a recursive make invocation, taking care to `export` the target-specific variable. But yuk.

Comment: That was a good thought but a quick test doesn't seem to show secondary expansion working for this. I expect a quirk of how the code works since it would seem to make sense for that to work.

Comment: @etan: yes, I found your earlier explanation of why it doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679137/target-specific-variables-in-a-makefile-prerequisites

Comment: @rici Seems like solid reasoning. I'm glad I thought of it. =) (I would have been happier to have remembered it now though. =P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with this for instance (considering you won't call make with multiple target at once):

```
OBJ := foo1.o foo2.o

ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "target2"
OBJ := foo3.o foo4.o
endif

target1 target2: application

application: $(OBJ)
    $(LD) $^
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.