# How to define a variable and then compile in a target [Makefile]

Tags: c++, makefile

Having a Makefile i just want to adjust a variable and then compile, if i call a specific target. I have a working solution, how ever, it is not a nice one.

How i compile:

```
make
```

How i want to change a variable:

```
make debug
```

What needs to happen (how it works somehow):

```
debug:
    @make TAG=debug
```

I basically call make in a make process, which does the work, but doesn't seem to be correct either. I am looking for something like:

```
debug:
    TAG=debug
    jump to first line and do the job
```

Comment: Just run `make TAG=debug` in the first place yourself?

Comment: because there is no autocompletion, furthermore i like to have debug-clean and debug-distclean also....

Comment: Well, the usual way would be something like `make BUILD_TYPE=Debug`

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG=release

build:
    @echo $(TAG)

debug: TAG=debug
debug: build

release: build
```

Usage:

```
> make
release
> make release
release
> make debug
debug
```

**Update:**
Using `TAG` in build prerequesites:

```
TAG=release

pre:
    @echo pre build $(TAG)

build: pre
    @echo $(TAG)

debug: TAG=debug
debug: build

release: build
```

Output:

```
~/workspace (master) $ make build
pre release
release
~/workspace (master) $ make debug
pre debug
debug
~/workspace (master) $ make release
pre release
release
```

Comment: This works as long as the value of `TAG` isn't needed in the prerequisite list of any other targets.

Comment: @EtanReisner Could you explain? `TAG` is set to `release` by default in my example

Comment: Yes, and that value will work in prerequisites. Try it with `TAG=debug` and use of `$(TAG)` in a prerequisite of `build`. (See the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33135067/258523) for a discussion I had about this though my parts are deleted at this point.)

Comment: And actually [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9311743/258523) covers exactly that issue and a workaround.

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't get what you are trying to say. I updated my answer and added a prerequiste to `build`. Works for me.

Comment: You put the variable expansion in the recipe of the prerequisite. Don't. Put it in the prerequisite list directly. (Think a `config.$(TAG)` file.)