# Makefile for many outputs with different dependencies

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How would I create a Makefile for many outputs with different dependencies?

I have a bunch of sequentially named source files (e.g. `1.s`, `2.s`, `3.s`, ..., `n.s`) where `n` can be a pretty big number. Each of these should produce their own executable and link with some libraries, e.g. `utils.o`.

This is what I have so far, using static pattern rules:

```
BINS = 1 2 3 4 5
ASFLAGS = --gstabs

all: $(BINS)

$(BINS): %: %.o utils.o
    ld -o $@ $^

.PHONY: all clean
clean:
    rm -f $(BINS) *.o
```

This works great if all of the outputs are built the same way, but some of the outputs need to link to some extra libraries, e.g. `2` and `3` needs to link to `2_lib.o` and `3_lib.o` respectively, and `3` additionally needs to link to `another_lib.o`, and the rest should just make like normal.

I was able to use target-specific variables with secondary expansion (credit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22679137/19352764)):

```
BINS = 1 2 3 4 5
ASFLAGS = --gstabs
2: EXTRA_LIBS = 2_lib.o
3: EXTRA_LIBS = 3_lib.o

all: $(BINS)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(BINS): %: %.o $$(EXTRA_LIBS) utils.o
    ld -o $@ $^

.PHONY: all clean
clean:
    rm -f $(BINS) *.o
```

But I am curious, does a better solution exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need extra prerequisites you can just add them directly; no need for all this extra stuff:

```
BINS = 1 2 3 4 5
ASFLAGS = --gstabs

2: 2_lib.o
3: 3_lib.o

all: $(BINS)

$(BINS): %: %.o utils.o
        ld -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Sure.  You have `$^` in your recipe, and `$^` expands to all the prerequisites, and you've defined those as extra prerequisites, so they will appear in `$^`.