# Makefiles: Alternate between two different prerequisites in the same implicit goal

Tags: unix, build, makefile

I'm writing my very first makefile and I'm stuck on a problem.

I have a bunch of prerequisites, of which the first one is a template that needs to be in a special position. I get to do this like so:

```
target : req1 req2 req3
    command $(filter-out $<,$^) $@ --template=$<
```

The thing is, sometimes I need to switch that template for another one while leaving the other prerequisites alone, so that

```
# Changing just the first prerequisite
target : req1b req2 req3
    command $(filter-out $<,$^) $@ --template=$<
```

I'm searching for a way to achieve this using the goal I have right now, without writing an ad-hoc explicit goal, maybe calling `make` with an argument or something similar, but I know too little about makefiles to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is you will want to use a variable, how you set that variable is up to you.  One way is to pass a variable via the command line.   Your Makefile would look like:

```
target : $(REQ_ONE) req2 req3
    command $(filter-out $<,$^) $@ --template=$<
```

and then do `make target REQ_ONE=reg1` or `make target REQ_ONE=reg1b`

If you have a preferred default that you wish to use (say `req1`) and you  want to use the alternative in rarer circumstances you could use the modified forms of the previous example.

```
# only set if the variable doesn't exist
REQ_ONE ?= req1

target : $(REQ_ONE) req2 req3
    command $(filter-out $<,$^) $@ --template=$<
```

Finally, a variant on this approach is to have your Makefile call make with a variable assignment:

```
# only set if the variable doesn't exist
REQ_ONE ?= req1

target2:
    $(MAKE) target REQ_ONE=req1b

target : $(REQ_ONE) req2 req3
    command $(filter-out $<,$^) $@ --template=$<
```

Another solution is to use secondary expansion as demonstrated in this [SO post on target specific variables as a prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312106/1607832).

Comment: The options with target-specific variables won't work.  You can't use target-specific variables in the prerequisite list of a target; their values are only available inside the recipe (or you could use secondary expansion).  The sub-make variation would work.  Really the question is flawed, from a make point of view.  It's just not in make's nature to work with the same target being built using different prerequisites.  Doing this breaks all kinds of things.  If you want targets built two different ways, you should create two different targets.